# Which is the default font for chinese character in debian9 or later?

Tags: debian, fonts

In my memory the installed debian can't show Chinese character before version debian9 or 8,you have to install fonts for Chinese character otherwise all Tofu would be full of the screen after installation.Now i am sure that for  debian10 and later version ,it is no need to install any font to render Chinese character again,i wonder which default font is configured already in debian10(11) for Chinese character?

Comment: Default font for what application? In what graphic or non-graphic environment? What do you mean by *Tofu* here?

Comment: Any Chinese character would not be shown normally if you don't install fonts for it,any Chinsee character would be shown as a square ,any different two Chinese character would be shown as the same square, we say it is 方块 or 豆腐块 ,in English it is Tofu.